# ForEach Cloudformation with collection in size n

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I need to create n routes in route table, and I want to declate each route in configurations file and each environment has it's own relevant routes. So I want to use Fn::ForEach I have the following configurations file:

dev.yaml:

```
Properties:
  TgwCidrs:
    DevOpsTgwRoute: 1.1.1.1/24  
    TestTgwRoute: 2.2.2.2/2
    . . .
    . . .
```

And the template.yaml file:

```
Resources:
  TGWDevOpsDevWRoute:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Route"
    DependsOn: TransitGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/vpc/privet-route-table}}'
      DestinationCidrBlock: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, TgwCIdrs, DevOpsDev]
      TransitGatewayId: !Ref CentralizedTransitGatewayId
```

I want to use the ForEach function to generate n routes according to the configuratoins file, Is it possible to pass to the ForEach the collection that exists in the dev.yaml file? If yes any example that I can use will be appreciated.

Comment: Examples of Fn::ForEach in the Resources section [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-foreach-example-resource.html).

Comment: I already saw this, but I have different case, I want to pass the collection not the items within the collection hard coded.